# Use domain username on SQL server reporting services installed in a server which is part of a Workgroup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

I have installed SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008. This system is configured to be part of a Workgroup and all the users in our organisation are part of a domain. I am trying to use the reporting services that is part of SQL Server.

I was trying to give "System User" permission to a user who is part of the domain through the "New System Role Assignment" page of the "Report Manager". It keeps throwing the error "user name or group name is not recognized.(rsUnknownUserName)"
Is it because the server is in a workgroup or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well according to MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186541.aspx):

> **Group or User**
>   Type the name of a group or user account in your
>   domain. If the report server is running under a *local account*, **you
>   must specify local groups or users**. If the report server is running
>   under a domain account, you must specify domain groups or users. Enter
>   the account in this format: `<domain>\<account>.`

I would take that to mean you will not be able to do what you are wanting. A work around I would try is to create a local group, adding the domain group/user to it, and try to add that local group to the new system role. It has been a while since I have supported a mixed environment so I am not sure if you can add domain accounts to a workgroup computer. You might have to check with your AD admin for assistance on that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, a workgroup is just a collection of computers on a local area network (LAN) that share common resources. They provide easy sharing of files, printers. But they don't provide shared security, like a domain. There doesn't exist something like workgroup users (as the domain users which can be used on all domain machines).

So you'll need to use a local user on the reporting machine for your reporting purposes.